# Mosquito vs Human: Swapping the roles

Tags: immunology, human-genetics, virology, malaria, biomedical-engineering

Is there a known mosquito-specific lethal (for some relevant species of mosquitos) virus that you could safely (for the humans) put into the blood of living humans? Is it technically possible to engineer humans to produce such a virus?